# MySQL - SUM DateTime?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need sum datetime values, but I don't know how I can do this.

I've the table:

[image]

And my query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(h.dtplay) AS Time 
FROM 
    tblhistory AS h, 
    tblgame AS g 
WHERE 
    h.idgame = g.id AND 
    g.description = gameName;
```

But, when I run that query, my result is:

[image]

Why it's incorrect?

**EDIT**

I change the format from datetime to time in my table:

[image]

So, I need sum the time values.

**EDIT 2**

The correct query:

```
SELECT 
   SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(h.DtPlay))) AS Time 
FROM 
   tblhistory AS h, 
   tblgame AS g 
WHERE 
   h.idgame = g.id AND 
   g.description = gameName;
```

Thanks for @Newbee Dev and @EhsanT  :)

Comment: Did you try using the `TIME` data type?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I tested, and don't work again. The query sum all numbers like as Integer and ignore time format =/

Comment: You might need to format the time values before you can do anything I believe.

Comment: @PraveenKumar But in my table the values already in the time format

Comment: Have you tried `SEC_TO_TIME` and `TIME_TO_SEC`?

Comment: @EhsanT isn't work too

Comment: Can you show how did you use it please?

Comment: @EhsanT Sure! First try:  SELECT SUM(SEC_TO_TIME(`h`.`dtplay`)) AS Time ... and the result are 1580. Second try: SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`h`.`dtplay`)) AS Time ... and the result are 620. I need see that value in time format

Comment: I mean what will this query return? `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(h.dtplay))) AS Time FROM tblhistory AS h`? (I just simplified you query)

Comment: @EhsanT `SEC_TO_TIME => 1580` and `TIME_TO_SEC => 620`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127508/discussion-between-ehsant-and-jose-felipe-blum-de-araujo).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First: Format your datetime into just time

```
Date_format(DtPlay, '%h:%i:%s')
```

then convert it into just a seconds

```
Time_to_sec(Date_format(DtPlay, '%h:%i:%s')
```

after converting it you can now sum them

```
Sum(Time_to_sec(Date_format(DtPlay, '%h:%i:%s'))
```

finally the result is now ready and just return it's format as time format

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( DtPlay ) ) ) FROM tblhistory
```

[**Sample Result**](https://gyazo.com/bcd679a84bdf052065641882181ad7b1)

Comment: I tested and works fine when I remove the `DATE_FORMAT`, thanks

Comment: @JoseFelipeBlumdeAraujo can you mark it as answer :)

Comment: @JoseFelipeBlumdeAraujo ah so it still works without converting it to date_format

Answer (score -1):

Can you give a little more information about what you are trying to do. Because I can't think a scenario where you would want to sum years. 
The result you are getting seems correct to me, since you can split it in second, minutes, hours, days, month and years.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: I'm saying the result is correct so actually it is an answer

Comment: This is not an answer, If you need to communicate with the OP and ask questions for clarification about the question, please use comment section instead of posting an answer!